# Is there a carousel that uses DIV containers for separate content instead of lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcarousel

Instead of:

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango"> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75"  
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" 
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75"  
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
<li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75"  
height="75" alt="" /></li> 
</ul>
```

I would like a carousel that uses DIV containers. The reason I need this is because I'm making a Tumblr theme, which for those who don't know is a blogging network where you post content on a "Dashboard" and the content is generated dynamically from Tumblr through tags. Lists like this do not have the ability to produce new tags for new content.

Comment: you should be able to generate LIs dinamically just fine using loops in tumblr, if it still looks like Smarty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used both Nivo (mentioned earlier, http://nivo.dev7studios.com) and jQuery Cycle plug-in, found at: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Both are good and work very well.

Nivo is slightly easier to set up but the thumbnails-pager option takes a bit more effort because the CSS modifications are not as clearly documented.

jQuery Cycle is more of a workhorse, and will handle not only images, but `div`'s with structured content.

jQuery Cycle has plenty of examples to pick from, especially if you need pagers (whether index numbers or image thumbnails).

Comment: Would it be able to generate a new slide for dynamically loaded content?

Comment: And each slide would have to be able to hold things like text, music players, etc.. I need it for a Tumblr theme idea.

Comment: jQuery Cycle handles **non-image content** quite well as demonstrated at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html (see example towards bottom of page)

Comment: This is great, it's one of the best carousels I've come across... However, I don't see an option to place controls on the non-image content slide. I tried but it just keeps scrolling to the right. Any way to do this?

Comment: Well I figured it out, but I want the scroll right feature... It seems the scroll right is automatic. You can use the fade animation on non-image content but the scroll right animation just keeps on going. Anyway to disable this?

Comment: Nevermind! Haha wow I should read next time. It's all fixed. Wow this is definatley the best I've ever used, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check these out:

- http://slidesjs.com/
- http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery one. You could even change it to just images and rule out divs altogether. 
http://jsfiddle.net/QnkEm/4/

Updated to use the supplied images.